# EclipseLink error with batch fetch - NullPointerException

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

EclipseLink 2.3.0 - same issue on 2.3.2 but stack trace from 2.3.0

Running into an issue where batch fetch and fetch join are not playing nicely with each other.  I have a query like

```
select obj from Parent
   left join fetch obj.elementCollection
```

with hints `eclipselink.batch = obj.oneToMany` and `eclipselink.batch.type = IN`.

in the `Parent` object, there is an `@ElementCollection` and a `@OneToMany`, where the `@OneToMany` is batch-fetched and the `@ElementCollection` is joined (batch fetch on it instead seemed to have no effect).

It breaks with the below error; changing the batch type from `IN` to `EXISTS` makes it work.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.extractBatchKeyFromRow(OneToOneMapping.java:624)
   at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.extractResultFromBatchQuery(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:524)
   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.valueFromBatchQuery(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:294)
   at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.batchedValueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:215)
```

Any ideas - am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: After a quick look into eclipselink source code: it seems to be a bug in eclipselink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the 2.4 release, and log a bug if the error still occurs.

You should be able to batch fetch the element collection as well.  If you cannot, please log a bug with a test case.

Comment: I *do* get the same error with 2.4.x under the same circumstance, when I mix "fetch join" of the `@ElementCollection` with batch fetch of the `@OneToMany` with "IN".  However, batch fetch of `@ElementCollection` now works with "IN", so I can batch fetch both.  Should I still log a bug or am I not supposed to be able to mix batch fetch and fetch join like that?

Comment: It looks like I can batch-fetch the @ElementCollection with 2.3.2 as well as long as I remove the "fetch join".  So the real problem is inability to mix fetch-join and batch-fetch, or to mix batch fetch strategies.

Comment: What is the fix version?